# svn errors E170013 and E180001

Tags: svn

While importing folder with my project (folder `WebApplication2`) to svn repo (folder `subver`) I'm getting errors:

```
svn E170013 Unable to connect to a repository at URL
svn E180001 Unable to open repository
```

Result of `svn import` command execution:

[image: result of svn import command execution]